# Do I need to create a component for showing up my Navigation Menu?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I already created a Navigation menu component to show my menu in desktop mode. Then I created a separate side drawer component and I used it whenever the screen size varies. One of my friends told me we don't need to create a side drawer menu component. And further he suggested we can do with CSS to make the navigation component without a side drawer component.

Comment: You don't need separate component for drawers. You can have a look at this link which perfectly explains your scenario: https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#drawer

Comment: thanks i will look at it

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to use the same component / markup for both desktop and mobile menu. Maybe a bit tricky to just use CSS to achieve it, you could also use JS or jQuery. However, this also depends on the designs and how both menus are meant to be working. In some scenarios it's just simpler and faster to create two separate menu components.

Comment: Thanks, @ASG In My case we were using react here it involves too many events too, So I went for an extra component